# What does renormalization of a measure mean?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, lebesgue-measure

A short question!

I was reading a paper when I faced the statement "Invariant measure $\mu^*$ can be constructed as a renormalized restriction of the Lebesgue measure to the set $J_0 \cup S(j_0) \cup \cdots \cup S^{m-1}(J_0)$"

My question is that what renormalized restriction mean? Does it mean the following?
\begin{align}
\mu^*:= \frac{\mathrm{Leb}|_{J_0 \cup S(j_0) \cup \cdots \cup S^{m-1}(J_0)}}{\mathrm{Leb}(I)} \, ,
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{Leb}$ is the Lebesgue measure and $I$ is the whole interval we are talking about.